# Multivariable Function Approximation Review Paper

Tags: approximation, multivariate-polynomial

I am doing some research on function approximation for a general multivariable equation. (i.e., I have a function f that depends on $x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n$. Given many data points of f at multiple known positions ($x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n$), I want to find a good approximation for $f$. I am looking for some review papers that outline a broad overview of the different fitting techniques to approximate the function in different forms. Does anyone have any recommendations on a good entry-level paper?